# In Google script, newly added forms response sheet is not showing up

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In js, I am opening a google sheet, performing some functions to it. I am then opening a google form, and setting the response destination to that sheet. This automatically adds a new worksheet. However, in the script, the new work sheet is not showing up.

Here's the relevant code:

```
var userCBsheet = SpreadsheetApp.open(userCBfile);
Logger.log("Sheet Count 1: " +userCBsheet.getNumSheets());
//this shows 8 sheets correctly

var formLL = FormApp.openById(userLLfile.getId());
formLL.setDestination(FormApp.DestinationType.SPREADSHEET,userCBsheet.getId());

Logger.log("Sheet Count 2: " +userCBsheet.getNumSheets());
//Still shows 8
```

So then I tried a few options like adding a sleep, or reopening the file with a new variable.

```
//same as above, then added
var cbid=userCBsheet.getId(); 
var userCBsheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById(cbid);
Logger.log("Sheet Count 3: " +userCBsheet2.getNumSheets());
//still shows 8
```

If I let the function complete, then run a simple check, it works:

```
function junk() {
  var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName(theName);
  var file = files.next();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(file.getId())
  Logger.log("Sheet Count 4: " +ss.getNumSheets());
  //this returns 9 (as it should).
}
```

So the question is how can I access the newly created tab after it has been added to the sheet via the setDestination function of the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add SpreadsheetApp.flush() after changing the form destination like this:

```
var formLL = FormApp.openById(userLLfile.getId());
   formLL.setDestination(FormApp.DestinationType.SPREADSHEET,userCBsheet.getId());
SpreadsheetApp.flush()
Logger.log("Sheet Count 2: " +userCBsheet.getNumSheets());
```

Comment: Bless you! knew it had to be something simple. I don't have enough rep to up the answer publicly, but that worked. Thank you!

Comment: Glad it worked for you. You can approve the answer by clicking the check mark to the left of the answer. Rep does not matter for that. Thanks.